# Modify into Fixed Header

Tags: html, css

I want to modify my old website template header into fixed. So, whenever I scroll down or top, the header will keep on top of screen.

I know that I only need add `position: fixed;` into my stylesheet, but since this is old website, when I added this code, the rest content will go up and the header placed above the content.

Are there any ways to make the header fixed, but without make the content go up?

I have tried to add `margin-top: 50px` to make header and content still in old position, but since the header will be dynamic (height of header will be change based on user), this way will not so good to use.

Thank you.

Comment: show your code or fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `body` a `padding-top:50px` to force the gap

If the header has variable height, you will have to use javascript to re-assign new padding to the body..

jquery solution

```
$(function(){
    $('body').css({'padding-top': $('#header').height()});
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I used this method into my main container and it is work like magic!